# Closing pop up window after it was loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, popup

I have such issue. I need to open popup window pressing button(this action is implemented). Then after pop up window will be loaded it should be closed.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popupButton').click(function() {
         signinWin = popupwindow([url],
                 "SignIn",960,630);
         signinWin.focus();
         signinWin.onload=function(){
             var code =  getQueryVariable("code");
             if(code != null){
                signinWin.opener.location.reload(true); 
                signinWin.close();
             }
        }
    });
});
```

What should I do to close pop up? Cause signinWin.close(); doesn't work in onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `window` `height` , `width` at third parameter to `window.open()` using string `"width=960,height=630"` ; utilizing `document.write` to close `window` `signinWin`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#popupButton").click(function() {
    var signinWin = window.open("/url/", "SignIn","width=960,height=630");
    signinWin.focus();
    var code = getQueryVariable("code");
    if (code != null) {
        signinWin.document.write("<script>this.close()<\/script>");
        setTimeout(function() {
          location.reload(true); 
        }, 1);
    };
  });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/scuxhbva/

Comment: You don't understand, function popupwindow() opens new window. It uses window.open `function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
   var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
   var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
   return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
 } ` but the problem is in that I need close window only afte it was loaded

Comment: THANK YOU. This line helped me to close popup window: signinWin.document.write("<script>this.close()<\/script>");